# AWS - Set a global budget for a project?

Tags: terraform

I am working on a Terraform project to create, update or delete AWS sandboxs for every new employee in my company. However, we would like to have a fix budget for every sandbox and if possible, not being able to exceed that budget. I read about AWS Budget Actions but I am not sure what will be the best way to integrate it with my current code.

**main.tf**

```
## this is creating a new project and I would like to set a budget of $50 for this account

resource "aws_organizations_account" "account" {
  name      = "sandbox"
  email     = "new-user+sandbox@company.com"
  role_name = "myOrganizationRole"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create [aws_budgets_budget](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/budgets_budget) and [aws_budgets_budget_action](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/budgets_budget_action) resources in the new account. To create resources in the new account, you need to create a provider for that account by assuming the administration role that was created:

```
provider "aws" {
  alias   = "sandbox"
  region  = "us-east-1"
  ...
  // Specify your credentials source, same as you use for the provider you used for the aws_organizations_account resource
  ...
  assume_role {
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::${aws_organizations_account.account.id}:role/${aws_organizations_account.account.role_name}"
  }
}
```

And now you can use that provider to create the budget resources in the new sandbox account (note the `provider` input parameters):

```
resource "aws_budgets_budget" "example" {
  provider          = aws.sandbox
  name              = "example"
  budget_type       = "USAGE"
  limit_amount      = "10.0"
  limit_unit        = "dollars"
  time_period_start = "2006-01-02_15:04"
  time_unit         = "MONTHLY"
}

resource "aws_budgets_budget_action" "example" {
  provider           = aws.sandbox
  budget_name        = aws_budgets_budget.example.name
  ...
}
```

Comment: They don't necessarily need to be in the new account, they could be in the main account, using a `LinkedAccount` filter to restrict them to the new account.

Comment: Good point. And that probably is the best approach for a multi-account organization: have either a dedicated account for managing budgets throughout the entire organization, or set budgets in a dedicated account for each Organizational Unit.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser. I just figured out that it's easy to create new AWS with Terraform but impossible to delete it (at least using Terraform): `Deleting this Terraform resource will only remove an AWS account from an organization. Terraform will not close the account. The member account must be prepared to be a standalone account beforehand. See the AWS Organizations documentation for more information.`